# Which is better: public javascript CDN or self-hosted combined javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, browser-cache, cdn

My web page uses several javascript libraries, like jquery, jquery-ui, underscore, backbone, and a few other well-known jquery plugins.

Now I face a dilemma, I could:

1. use a public CDN that hosts all of these libraries. And if the user has visited another site using the same CDN, the scripts may have been cached. But since each library is separate, the page need to include many script tags, hence many http requests.
2. Combine all the required scripts into one (including my own script files) and host it on my own server. Only one request for everything, but I couldn't serve the script faster than CDN, and I cannot take advantage of the cache.

From your own experience, which is better?

And I want to estimate whether enough websites use the mentioned CDN (if many well-known sites use them, then the probability of scripts being cached is high), how can I investigate? I tried googling the script src attribute, but it seems google doesn't index that.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based. But why do you think the browser not is using the cache if you combine them to one? Certainly not on first pageload, but it is unlikely all users have cached all the scripts you are using from same CDN sources anyway.

Comment: @davidkonrad I understand how the cache works. I mean the freely cached versions by prior requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using only 1-2 libraries, a good practice is too include the CDN version, with a fallback to local version. This is the practice that most HTML boilerplates/frameworks use .e.g .

http://html5boilerplate.com/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//myserver/js/libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

However,you are using a lot of libraries, so there might be dependencies, and specific ordering of them on the page, and some of them might not be present on standard CDNs,so you will have to anyway include some of your javascripts from your server.
Hence for your case, a better bet would be to use good combining/versioning of all your javascript code into 1-2 files .e.g one for libraries(usually not touched), and one for your own custom code(cache busted when you make changes to it).

Comment: This fallback method is very effective. I used document.createElement and append to <head>, but that doesn't guarantee script execution order. Document.write seems to work, at least for Chrome. Does this work across browsers?

Comment: And how about css fallback: use document.write in css tag's onerror callback, to write a new <link>, will that work?

Comment: No, combining isn't a good solution. Think about the user's cache. Yes, it might be faster the first time the user requests the page, but he doesn't have the lib in his cache for other uses, on other websites.